# Access 2013 report/forms not using modified query

Tags: ms-access

I am modifying a very old access app that had been upgraded numerous times.  It may have started out as 2003.  I am running with 2013.  I modified a query to filter on a column that I just added to a table. Neither my form nor my reports is using the modified query.  I know this because I added a column to a table and then modified the query to filter on this column.  the query runs fine.  The reports and form are definitely using the old query.  The app also uses VB6 code which actually adds more SQL based on the report selected.  If I create a totally new report it will execute the new query.  I don't want to create all new reports.  And please I know VB6 is old also, but this company is going out of business and it's just a keep it going type of organization.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is going to be figuring out where the report gets its data from at run-time.  Because you say that there's VB6 code that alters the SQL, this could be complicated.

There are a number of ways this can change, and with the information in the question at the moment, it's not possible for me to narrow it down, but there are some places that you can look to check.

A report's data can be specified in a number of ways.

- You can choose a table or query as the datasource in the properties of the report.  If this was what's happening then your report should have changed as soon as you modified the query.  So it might not be.
- A report can have its own query defined using that property. This can be a select statement that uses tables and other queries, chooses specific fields and applies filters.
- You say there's a bunch of VB6 that alters the query too.  (Are you sure it's VB6 and not VBA? probably doesn't matter much).  This will change where you need to look.

So what I'd do is:

- Look at the properties for the report and find out what the data source is.  See if it's just a query name or an SQL statement.  If it's an SQL statement, fire it up in the builder and see if you can find the query that you modified, or reapply the modifications and see if that works.

If that doesn't work, then you're going to need to look at the VB code.  Find the code that modifies the SQL for this report. Most likely, there'll be a button that user clicks that runs a bunch of code, that updates the SQL and launches the report.  Stick a breakpoint in there and step through until you see some SQL being constructed, then work out how to alter the SQL from there.

Most likely you'll have two strategies:

- The VB code constructs SQL raw, which looks vaguely like the SQL in the query,  but with different criteria.  So you could use the modified SQL from your modified query to model the changes you need to make in the VB constructed SQL
- The VB code does something like `SELECT * FROM [TheQuery] WHERE` and just adds criteria.  This would probably make your life easier, but it's probably not what's going on because modifying the query didn't change anything.

Comment: Well interesting enough I removed the record source from the report property sheet and low and behold, it still executed properly...  I am assuming this is telling me the record source query is not even being used, would you agree with this assessment?

Comment: @lesslag yes, I agree. It's probably being populated in code just before launching the report.

Comment: Thank you for your help!   @GregHNZ